# No Log file is generated -- python using logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

**code**

I am using logging module to create log file.It checks the platform and provide method to create logfile as per the platform

```
import  os,platform,logging

if platform.platform('windows'):
    logging_file=os.path.join(os.getenv('HOMEDRIVE'),os.getenv('HOMEPATH'),'test.log')
else:
    logging_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'),'test.log')

print"logging to",logging_file

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s :%(message)s',filename=logging_file, filemode='w')


logging.DEBUG("start of the program")
logging.info("doing something")
logging.warning("u are gonna die")
```

Comment: If the indentation in your code correct? If so, maybe you don't get a log file because you're on windows?

Comment: Are you getting any error? which os are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided is not indented properly and you should use `logging.debug` instead of `logging.DEBUG` since the later is an Integer constant used to represent log level. Here is the updated code

```
import  os,platform,logging

if platform.platform('windows'):
    logging_file=os.path.join(os.getenv('HOMEDRIVE'),os.getenv('HOMEPATH'),'test.log')
else:
    logging_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'),'test.log')

print"logging to",logging_file

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s :%(message)s',
                    filename=logging_file,
                    filemode='w')


logging.debug("start of the asdfasdfprogram")
logging.info("doing something")
logging.warning("u are gonna die")
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are using a unix system , the below statement is wrong -

```
platform.platform('windows')
```

The `platform.platform` function always returns the underlying platform as a string, later on you are directly testing the `string` in if condition, which will always return true, hence it always assumes you are in windows system.

You need a condition like -

```
if 'windows' in platform.platform().lower():
```

Also, as k4vin said - if this isn't a type you should be using `logging.debug` instead of `logging.DEBUG` , the first is a function, where as the second is the integer used to indicate the logging level `DEBUG` .

```
logging.debug("start of the program")
```

Answer (score 0):

The logging handlers should be cleaned before creating the basicconfig

**Code**

```
import  os,platform,logging

if 'windows' in platform.platform().lower():
    logging_file=os.path.join(os.getenv('HOMEDRIVE'),os.getenv('HOMEPATH'),'test.log')
else:
    logging_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'),'test.log')

print"logging to",logging_file
logging.getLogger('').handlers = []
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s :%(message)s',filename=logging_file, filemode='w')    

logging.DEBUG("start of the program")
logging.info("doing something")
logging.warning("u are gonna die")
```

you could view this [link](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) for more information